# Page of StackExchange cross-site sidebar ads?

Tags: feature-request, advertising

I find myself occasionally hanging out on the StackOverflow front page, seeing an interesting question advertised on another StackExchange site (like Gaming, SE, or English.SE), but then clicking into one of the questions, only to push the back button and see a different ad.

This isn't necessarily bad, but to see the ad I remember seeing, I will refresh the front page as many times as I need to in order for the ad to come up again.  I'm not sure if this is bad for the site or not.

So my question:  Since I like looking at these ads, would it be possible to make a page that contains all of the current StackExchange cross-site ads at the same time instead of hammering the front page?

I understand that the "StackExchange hot questions" button in the upper left corner contains similar information, but sometimes I looking at the questions in the site's theme motivates me to go there more than a general list does.

Comment: I do this **all the time**, and I'm happier when I'm browsing on my iPad, where Mobile Safari doesn't refresh the linked question when I go back.

Comment: I simply use StackExchange.com for this purpose (in contrast to the dropdown), especially because its always up to date while the handmade ads aren't