# Is there a gallery for the ads used to promote beta or launched sites in the Stack Exchange network?  How to get such an ad?

Tags: discussion, advertising, stackexchange-2.0, gallery

I was just browsing the [**Personal Finance & Money** Stack Exchange](http://money.stackexchange.com) where I am one of the moderators.

Today, and not for the first time, I noticed the following in my right sidebar: an attractive, artistically designed ad for [**Parenting** Stack Exchange](http://parenting.stackexchange.com) – which just like *PF & Money* is **still in beta**:

[image: parenting.stackexchange.com ad]

There's also a second one:

[image: parenting.se ad alternate]

**Is there a gallery of such ads for Stack Exchange sites, whether in beta or launched?**

I'm motivated to find out if there are attractive ads in rotation for *PF & Money* — because it is almost getting embarrassing to be the founding moderator of the [longest-running beta in the network](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1721/personal-finance-and-money), at 524 days and counting.  The folks from the Guinness book are about to come calling!

I presume I would not see an ad for *PF & Money* elsewhere on the SE network (if such an ad existed) while logged in because the system could be clever enough to know that I don't need to be marketed to for sites I actively participate at. (Is that so?)  Yet, I also wasn't able to find any clever ads for *PF & Money* while logged out of the network.  My browser's "Reload" button is sore and on strike now.

And last: if a site like *Personal Finance & Money* is **not** getting this kind of love from the graphically-talented ad designers at Stack Exchange, <strike>whose arm do we need to twist</strike> is there somebody we can ask politely to show us some love?  ;-)

Comment: Related: [Page of StackExchange cross-site sidebar ads?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/116855) (I didn't vote to close because this question asks a bit more than the one I've linked)

Comment: *"the system is clever enough to know that I don't need to be marketed to for sites I actively participate at"* - Admittedly I think it's entirely random, but I don't know that for a fact.

Comment: @TimStone Thanks.  I've added "How to get such an ad?" to the title, to make it clear there's more to this question than the one you linked.

Comment: some of the adverts can be found [in this M.SO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114442/open-source-advertising-sidebar-1h-2012) thread.

Comment: @tombull89 Thanks, but none of those ads you linked to are for promoting *Q&A sites in the Stack Exchange network*.  It is those I am asking about -- not the open source promos.

Comment: @ChrisW.Rea, apologies. I don't know of any similar lists for SE sites.

Answer (score 6):

There is no gallery of Stack Exchange ads, but that sounds like a pretty good idea.

House ads are not typically created until *after* a site graduates, but with the US tax season upon us, maybe this is a good time for a special project. We saw a rise in traffic on Money SE this time last year, so anything we can do now will only help us move along with the current. I'm on it. Jin?!

Comment: +1 for "*I'm on it.  Jin?!*"

Comment: Thanks!  Also, re: "House ads are not typically created until *after* a site graduates" .. Wondering, what made Parenting atypical?

Comment: @ChrisW.Rea I was, at the time, full-time CHAOS and trying to promote Parenting intra-network before I promoted it extra-network.